# Android app development error - multiple markers at this line

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have just started android development in eclipse with android and am trying to program a button, this is my code,

```
        package my.Apprentice;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class ApprenticeVoteActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);



            startVotingListener();


        }

        private void startVotingListener() {

            final Button startVoting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startVoting);

            startVoting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                } // Multiple markers at this line error shows here
            };)
        }
        }
```

The location of my error is commented above. I really have no idea on how to get rid of it, I have tried cleaning my project with no success. Does anyone have any ideas ? Thanks !

The Updated and working code is shown below:

```
    package my.Apprentice;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class ApprenticeVoteActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        startVotingListener();

    }

    private void startVotingListener() {

        final Button startVoting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startVoting);

        startVoting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try });

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

startVoting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        } // Multiple markers at this line error shows here
    }); // Sequence is wrong
```

Comment: Hmm, again when I try that I get an error on 'setOnClickListener' and 'View'

Comment: after removing the view. , I get, 'The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})' and 'OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type'

Comment: I have tried to add import android.view.View; - but this just generates more errors. The same as above and then it tells me to remove the overide.

Comment: Check if you are using correct Java version. Project -> Right Click -> Property -> Java Compiler.

Comment: I have just imported those two and it has got rid of some errors. I am running 1.6 . I am now left with one more error

new OnClickListener()*{

where * is, I have the red underlining, saying multiple markers

Comment: Right, I have restarted eclipse and I have no errors :D. So I am assuming that worked, thank you for your help  !

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to remove the ';' after the listener declaration ? Remove also the View reference :

```
startVoting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { <-- HERE

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            } // Multiple markers at this line error shows here
        };) // <--- HERE
```

Final :

```
startVoting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Just tried it, then I get an error on 'setOnClickListener' and 'View'

Comment: Thanks for reply, when I do that I get three errors, I get, 'The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})' and 'OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type'

Comment: Sorry I'm quite lost ... this is supposed to work, it matches what's written here : http://www.connorgarvey.com/blog/?p=93   I don't think this changes anything but try to remove the final keywords, it's useless here.